# upload file without refreshing the whole page in mvc razor

Tags: razor

I am working on  MVC 3 Razor. How to upload file without refreshing the whole page.My code below mentioned

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <input type='file' name='file' id='file' />
        <input type="Button" value="upload" />
    }
```

my problem is that i can not define action and controller within above mentioned Html.BeginForm().
so when i click upload button ,it go to action of controller.how to pass my uploaded files from view to controller.please help. if any demo sample is available,let me share as per my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUploadss", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, 
                                  new {enctype ="multipart/form-data"})) 
{ 
        <input type='file' name='file' id='file' />
        <input type="submit" value="upload" />
}
```

Go to ur Controller and use this code,

```
 public ActionResult FileUploadss(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
       if(file.ContentLength>0)
            {
            }
    }
```